# Border radius cutting off right border on Safari for Mac

Tags: safari, webkit, css

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Check out the attached JSFiddle in Safari on a Mac - http://jsfiddle.net/cbrauckmuller/6e4gM/1/

Here is what I'm seeing -

[image]

CSS:

```
input[type=text], div.test {
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="margin: 20px;">
     <input type="text" value="Your mom" />
</div>

<div style="margin: 20px;">
    <div class="test">Your mom</div>
</div>
```

For some reason, Safari is cutting off the right border of the element. It doesn't matter whether it's an input field or just a plain old <div> element. I kept just the CSS properties that I need to replicate the error. If you remove the border radius or the background color it fixes the problem, but I need to use these properties in my design. Any ideas on what's causing this?

I'm on Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Safari 6.0.2 Mountain Lion.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it works fine here, too. What exactly are you seeing? Do you have any Safari plugins installed that might be breaking things somehow?

Comment: That looks like a background image that's starting to repeat.

Comment: Hmm, no problems here. Safari 6.0.2 Mountain Lion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `margin-right: 2px`. Maybe it'll work.

Unfortunately, I can't to check it in Safari on Mack.